# MySQL default procedueres

Tags: mysql

Is [ANALYSE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/procedure-analyse.html) the only procedure that comes with MySQL 5+ by default?

For Example:

```
select * from mysql.user limit 1 PROCEDURE ANALYSE()
```

[sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/1280).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 100% sure it's the only one, yes. Unfortunately I can't find where I read about it.

**UPDATE**:

See [here](http://www.rbcafe.com/Softwares/MySQL/extending-mysql.html#adding-procedures) and in the source code. The `ANALYSE()` procedure is more like an example of what can be done.

> ANALYSE() is defined in the sql/sql_analyse.cc source file, which
>   serves as an example of how to create a procedure for use with the
>   PROCEDURE clause of SELECT statements. ANALYSE() is built in and is
>   available by default; other procedures can be created using the format
>   demonstrated in the source file.

Didn't find any more procedures in the source code, so I'd still state that there is just this one.